# "and" and "or" on Theano

Tags: theano

I run the following code:

```
import theano.tensor as T

print(T.eq(2, 1).eval())
print(T.eq(1, 1).eval())
print((T.eq(2, 1) and T.eq(1, 1)).eval())
print((T.eq(2, 1) or T.eq(1, 1)).eval())
```

The outcome is:

```
False
True
True
False
```

Why is this not "False, True, False, True"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because theano is a symbolic library, thing like `T.eq(1,2)` does not directly gets evaluated into boolean.

```
>>> bool(T.eq(1,2))
True
>>> type(T.eq(1,2))
<class 'theano.tensor.var.TensorVariable'>
```

The weird result in this question is due to logical operator working on non-boolean object.

```
>>> '123' and '456'
'456'
>>> '123' or '456'
'123'
```

Quoted from [here](http://www.thomas-cokelaer.info/tutorials/python/boolean.html), section 9.5:

> `x and y` Returns `x` if `x` is `False`, `y` otherwise
>
> `x or y`  Returns `y` if `x` is `False`, `x` otherwise

The correct way is to use bitwise operator:

```
>>> (T.eq(1,1) & T.eq(1,2)).eval()
array(False, dtype=bool)
>>> (T.eq(1,1) | T.eq(1,2)).eval()
array(True, dtype=bool)
```